# How to display UIAlertView without buttons on iOS 8?

Tags: objective-c, swift, uialertview, ios8

In an app I'm working on we have some legacy code that displays timed UIAlertViews at several points in the application. These are alert views that display for a certain amount of time (let's say 2 seconds) before they disappear.

These alert views don't have buttons, just a title and a message. Somehow these alert views worked just fine on iOS 5, 6 and 7, but on iOS 8 the message label isn't being displayed anymore.

Does anyone have a fix for this issue? I should note we're not interested in using UIAlertController, since that class is limited to iOS 8 and we need to support older versions as well.

So my question is as follows: is it possible on iOS 8 to display an UIAlertView with just a title and a message and **NO** buttons? (**PLEASE NOTE:** the message should be shown properly).

Comment: Show the code you use to display those alerts. Was it constructed with initWithTitle...? What are the arguments?

Comment: I could reproduce it using Xcode 6b6. This is obviously a bug.

Comment: I have exactly same issue.

Comment: @MarekR: I've described my approach to work around this issue below. I should note I cannot share any code (my employer won't allow it).

Comment: I'm really really glad you added `(PLEASE NOTE: the message should be shown properly)`, was about to post an embarrassingly unhelpful answer heh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone still struggling with this issue, I used the following approach:

I created an AlertController class that decided which version of an alert view to use. For iOS 7 and lower will default to the "build-in" UIAlertView. For iOS 8 I resorted to a custom alert view.

There are several custom alert views that could be used to create a modal dialog that displays for a few seconds. I based my custom alert view on the code from the [iOS Custom Alert View](https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview) project. Additionally I fixed the look and feel. Suffice to say, the default look and feel of this project doesn't closely match the iOS 7 / 8 look and feel, especially with regards to the buttons. The pop / hide animation is pretty well done though. Fixing the look and feel involved creating a custom dialog view class that uses `-drawRect:` to draw lines around buttons. The custom subview will also add it's own buttons.

An alternative project that might have a better look and feel out-of-the-box is [SDCAlertView](https://github.com/sberrevoets/SDCAlertView). If I would have found SDCAlertView before starting my work on fixing iOS Custom AlertView, I would probably have saved some time.

I should note I cannot share my code / changes. My employer would not like this at all.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code for your UIAlert:

```
        let alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Title"
        alert.message = "Message"
        alert.show()
```

It should display a UIAlert without a button.

Hope this can help you.